How do i wire up dependency injection for types in class libraries in an aspire host application?
I'm playing with Aspire and working on an app with Clean Architecture.
In my app I have a class library project.  In this project I have interface IMyMagic and a class MyMagicA: IMyMagic and class MyMagicB: IMyMagic.
I want to configure dependency injection so that the concrete class for IMyMagic comes from MyMagicA.
As I understand, one should do this configuration in the AppHost project in aspire.  When I give AppHost a dependency to MyClassLibrary, I can't see the members of MyClassLibrary in AppHost program.cs.  I only get a reference to the PROJECT MyClassLibrary because of the aspire magic.
What is the proper way to configure this dependency injection? Is there a way to do it in the AppHost? Or, if I'm using the IMyMagic instance in some other app (MyWebUI for instance) do I need to do the DI setup there? If yes, isn't that against the suggested aspire practices?

I'm not entirely clear on exactly what your question is... But I interpret it as "How do I configure a project to use a specific implementation of an interface inside my AppHost?"
To do that, you would pass down a configuration that tells your app which implementation of an interface to use and then let that project choose the implementation based on the passed down configuration. This is probably most easily done through arguments, but can also be done with environment variables.
In your Apphost class, using arguments:
// Add your project to the IDistributedApplicationBuilder
builder.AddProject<Projects.MyWebUI>("my-web-ui").WithArgs("MyMagicA");

And then inside the MyWebUi.Program.cs file:
if (args.Contains("MyMagicA"))
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyMagic, MyMagicA>();
}
// Handle the case where we are told to use MyMagicB
else if (args.Contains("MyMagicB"))
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyMagic, MyMagicB>();
}
// Probably have some fallback value if no matching argument was passed in,
// or throw exception.

AppHost, using environment variables:
// Environment variable is added as a key-value pair
builder.AddProject<Projects.MyWebUI>("my-web-ui").WithEnvironment("magic-key", "MyMagicA");

MyWebUi.Program.cs file:
// Get the value from environment variables using the key:
var magicKey = builder.Configuration["magic-key"];

if (magicKey == "MyMagicA")
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyMagic, MyMagicA>();
}
// Handle the case where we are told to use MyMagicB
else if (magicKey == "MyMagicB")
{
    builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyMagic, MyMagicB>();
}

